# How do I append a doubly link to point to the correct nodes, to print in reverse order?

Tags: c++

For an assignment we are to create a .h file with methods that define a Node struct then define an append function. The purpose the append function serves is to take an input that the main function asks for and create the same number of spots in the list, then print in reverse order. I have got the struct function but am stumped on the append function, I tried to model it after similar code and learn from it but have failed. I don't ask for the exact solution but instead hints or examples that will help me. This is my homework, so I intend to do it, but I would like help.
Here's the code:

**ReverseLinkedList.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "RevNode.h"

using namespace std;


void printReverse(Node* tail) {
    Node* curr = tail;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->prev;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int limit;
    cin >> limit;

    Node* A = new Node(); //A = temp
    A->data = limit;
    A->prev = NULL;
    A->next = NULL;

    Node* last = A;

    for (int i = 2; i < limit; i = i + i) {
        last = append(A, i);
    }

    printReverse(last);


    return 0;

}
```

**RevNode.h**

```
#ifndef RevNode_h
#define RevNode_h

// Define the Node struct below
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};


// Define the append function below
Node* append(Node* head, int value) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->data = value;
    n->prev = 0;
    n->next = 0;

    Node* curr = head;

    while (curr->next != 0) {
            head->next = curr;
        curr->prev = head;
    }
    return(n);

    }


// Do not write any code below this line
#endif#pragma once
```

Node* append is what I am struggling to figure out

Here is an example of a single list that printed out the element number and then the previous until it reached zero, exiting the program.

I deleted the example and am just looking for where to point in the append function, I can't really get it. An example input/output to give a better picture:

input:

4

output:

2

4

When checking through the website we use the code failed test case 1, "Your program produces less output than expected.

Please ensure your program produces all expected outputs."

While passing test case 2, "Your program behaves as expected."

Comment: 1) `return(n);` should be after the loop.

Comment: Thank you, fixed that! That was just a simple mistake, must've slipped my mind.

Comment: 2) `last = append(A, i);` : Since `A->prev` is `NULL`, the body of the loop(`while (curr->prev != NULL) {...}`) is not executed.

Comment: Ah, ok yeah thank you. A previous program with a similar issue (single linked lists) worked with `curr->next` when `next` was equals to `NULL`

Comment: edited some information, included previous example code

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain some points.

You try to append an element in lined list.

> head -> node 1 -> node 2 -> ... -> tail -> **new element**

So, if your input is tail, it simply add like this

```
tail->next = new_element;
new_element->prev = tail;
```

Now, let see what you did in your code

```
Node* curr = tail;

while (curr->prev != NULL) {
    n->prev = n->next;
    n->next = curr;
    n = curr;
    n = n->prev;

    return(n);
}
```

it is wrong logic: the `curr` doesn't not change so, if your tail has prev is not NULL, it is infinite loop.

I think the right approach here is the input of `append` function is node `head` and `value`, you run to the end of linked list, append new element after the `tail`.

Comment: could you check out the updated post? Tried to mess around a bit more